# handle user in gatsbyJs

Tags: reactjs, authentication, gatsby, directus

I created a website with GatsbyJs and directusCMS as the back end, I use a collection that stores data of "members", now I am stuck at making a dashboard or maybe a profile from the item in DirectusCMS.

i have already created a website that can send the data, but I wonder how can I retrieve the data with authentication and authorization. I can just link it to the cms, but the user will be able to view the other user data.

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/authentication-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to create a new User Role with limited permissions — and then authenticate in the Directus API with that user's token:

https://docs.directus.io/guides/roles.html

https://docs.directus.io/api/authentication.html#tokens

Comment: but, the data is for each collection right ? 
well, my case is like this I have a collection that store data of the people that save his/her profile and now I am thinking maybe each item can be accessed individually, or should I just make it in a different collection?

Comment: It seems like the `mine` and `role` permissions might be useful for what you're trying to scope: https://docs.directus.io/guides/permissions.html#collection-level

Also, in the upcoming v9 we have a full "dynamic permissions" system, so that will definitely solve you issues.